# How can I add two labels as an empty UITableView background instead of one in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` filled with data dynamically. Now I want to show a message that says there is no data in case there is no data. I want to add a longer message, so I've decided to add two labels since I don't know how to make a 2-level uilabel. This is my code so far:

```
override func tableView(tview: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 10))//self.view.bounds.size.height))
        var emptyLabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, -10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 10))//self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "There is no data over here."
        emptyLabel.font = emptyLabel.font.fontWithSize(10)
        emptyLabel2.text = "Please pull down the list to refresh or come back later"
        emptyLabel2.font = emptyLabel.font.fontWithSize(10)
        tview.backgroundView = emptyLabel
        tview.backgroundView = emptyLabel2
        if self.items.count == 0{
            emptyLabel.hidden = false
            emptyLabel2.hidden = false
            tview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
            return 0
        } else {
            emptyLabel.hidden = true
            emptyLabel2.hidden = true
            tview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return self.items.count;
        }
    }
```

But after doing so, I can only see the 2nd label. How can I display both of them in the center of the screen, one above the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only see second label because of these 2 lines of code:

```
    tview.backgroundView = emptyLabel
    tview.backgroundView = emptyLabel2
```

Here you override first label with the second. Only the second one appears as a result. However, there is lots of problems in your code. Let's tackle them one by one.

1. Make the label multiline. Use `numberOfLines` property to make the label multiline.

   ```
   emptyLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // Setting 0 makes the label multiline
   ```
2. You'll need to make it taller though to fit 2 lines of text so when initializing the label provide bigger frame:

   ```
   var emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))
   ```
3. Don't create views in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. This is a wrong place. Do it rather in `viewDidLoad`. `numberOfRowsInSection` might be called multiple times and you will end up with recreating views every time the method is called.

Comment: Thank you! one thought - when I put this line: `emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))` in my viewDidLoad() method then the label is not visible in `numberOfRowsInSection`, so I had to put it globally, but then I don't have the access to `self.view.bounds.size.width`. When I change it to `100` then it works, but the label is not centered horizontally. Is there any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var emptyLabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, -10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 10))
```

is setting the y origin to -10, which will not show up since it's height is only 10.

I think all you will need to o is set it to 0.